# Turn off scientific notation on float

Tags: c++

I'm trying to display number in standard notation

for example:

```
float f = 1230000.76
```

turns out to be,

```
1.23e+006
```

Answer (score 15):

There are two things found in iomanip that must be included. First is `fixed` and the second is `setprecision`

You need to write:

```
std::cout << fixed;  
std::cout << setprecision(2) << f;
```

`fixed` disables the scientific notation i.e. 1.23e+006 and fixed is a sticky manipulator so you need to disable it if you want to revert back to scientific notation.

Comment: Is "fixed" sticky for a given/current ofstream or all subsequent new ofstream ?

Answer (score 9):

Use -

```
cout.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
```

before printing out the floating point numbers.

More information can be found [here](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs1005/common/floatformats.html).

You can also set output precision with the following statement -

```
cout.precision(2);
```

or simply with -

```
printf("%.2f", myfloat);
```

Comment: Ok, it came up as `1230000.750000` can it be a bit more accurate?

Comment: You can set the precision using either with cout.precision(ACCURACY_THAT_YOU_WANT) before printing the floating point numbers or with printf("%.ACCURACY_THAT_YOU_WANTf", myFloat)

Comment: For most C/C++ environments, a `float` has 6 to 7 significant figures of precision.  Displaying it beyond that does not increase the accuracy.  If you want more precision in handling the value, change the datatype to `double`, which has about 15 significant figures of precision, or `long double` with about 19.

Comment: @use753231: I agree with wallyk, and there is a slight mistake that I made in my previous comment. I should have written PRECISION in place of ACCURACY. If float's accuracy doesn't work for you, then try changing the datatype to double or long double just like wallyk suggested.

Comment: How to achieve this if I'm using a file pointer? As in ,
` fp << (float) x << endl ;` ?