# double representation using cout

Tags: c++, c

I have a simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

double i=0.000006;

printf("%lf\n",i);
cout <<i<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

the output of which is :

```
pearl.236> ./a.out
0.000006
6e-06
pearl.237>
```

How can i achieve 0.000006 using the `cout` too?

the actual proble i have is i am redirecting this double to a string stream and later on i am printing it on screen.i want to know how we can store the actuall double representation inside the string stream.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn off scientific notation on float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301547/turn-off-scientific-notation-on-float)

Comment: Switch to printf immediately. You won't regret it. ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stream formatting is achieved with the help of [manipulators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/). 
The manipluators to specify  standard and scientific notation are `fixed` and `scientific`.

```
cout << fixed <<i<<endl;
```

Comment: There's also `setPrecision(int)` to control the number of decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [std::fixed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/fixed/)

```
std::cout << std::fixed << i << "\n";
```