# Conversion from double to string in c++

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, double, scientific-notation

I'm currently coding a project for my Computer Science module but I'm having the problem of my string value defaulting to scientific notation if there are too many decimal places in the double value.

I've tried the obvious solution with `ostringstream` and `.str()` but it makes it into notation. I have to compile to the C++98 standard, so I cannot use modern solutions like `std::to_string`.

I need the value to be casted into a string but it needs to maintain its formatting. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Double to string conversion without scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546113/double-to-string-conversion-without-scientific-notation)

Comment: Not a C# question, @UtkarshGupta

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn off scientific notation on float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301547/turn-off-scientific-notation-on-float)
Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301547/turn-off-scientific-notation-on-float

Answer (score 6):

I would use:

```
std::to_string(myDouble);
```

Comment: unfortunately requires C++11

Comment: In 2020 it's truly unfortunate if you don't have access to C++11. It happens, I maintain some pretty old C++ code my organization will not allow me to change, but I only write new stuff in C++03 or C++98 on demand and only if there is a really, really good reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you use at least C++17, you could use `std::to_chars()` from `#include <charconv>`.

```cpp
// `512` is here arbitrary, it is the max size of the output string. 
// Smaller values should be sufficient.
char buffer[512];
// Here 'std::chars_format::fixed' tells the `std::to_chars()` to 
// not use the scientific notation.
char* end = std::to_chars(std::begin(buffer), std::end(buffer), myDouble, std::chars_format::fixed).ptr;
// `end` the one-past-the-end pointer of the characters written to `buffer`.
```

This method is probably faster than the Emilien Lemaire's answer, however it's more verbose, and more error-prone. So this answer is only provided for completeness (as the performance gain may not worth it).

Moreover, unlike `std::to_string()`, the output string is locale-insensitive, so the double will always be formatted in the C locale (english locale).

Comment: Unfortunately, my course limits us to c++98 in order to make us understand the more fundamental principles of c++. I have tried to_string(<double>) but that too cuts it down to notation.

Comment: Then you could use `std::sprintf(myBuffer, "%f", myDouble)` (available in C++98). The format `%f` specify to use the decimal notation. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf for more detail.